# OutOfMemoryException in IObjectList.EnsureRelatedObjects

Tags: exception, out-of-memory, mdriven

I have this line of code:

`IObjectList allHolders = allHandlers.EnsureRelatedObjects("Holders");`

Process memory usage at this point is ~3 Gbyte and `allHandlers` contains ~16000 objects. `Holders` class is not very large, but about 50000 objects should be loaded.

It's possible that I actually depleted system memory, but I'd just like to know if there are any limitations in these parts of MDriven itself, that might throw this exception.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no hard internal limits. If you are on 64-bit and not explicitly have set x86 then only physical limits should apply.

If we need large blocks - and this may be the case during transport - we may encounter out of memory exceptions because there is no room for such a large block - even though there is plenty of fragmented free memory in smaller blocks.

If this is what you see you may want to chunk your data in 2 or more pieces.
You can also tweak the setting for how we do chunking internally for larger fetches :
Look at this property in the IPersistenceService

```
    /// <summary>
    /// EnsureRange will use this pagesize when chunking up fetches - default value is 100
    /// </summary>
    int PageSize { set; get; }
```